# Overriding config in application.properties

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to setup a spring cloud netflix eureka server. I'm trying to create multiple profiles to be able to run multiple instances of the application at a time locally without much hastle.

- Tried using the VM Option `spring.profiles.active` the spring boot app doesn't seem to honoring this option
- I Tried to override the properties in application.properties using environment variables but this did not work either. For example the `server.port` value defaults to 8080. This can be overridden in application.properties. However, if I try to override this using environment variables it is not respected.

application.properties

```
server.port=8082
```

application-local-1.properties

```
server.port=8083
```

application-local-2.properties

```
server.port=8084
```

- I've tried running the application using the VM Option `-Dspring.profiles.active" something like
- I've tried setting this on the environment variable

I'm trying to basically have the application read from the correct profile.

==================

**My IDE setup**

On Intellij I've setup a gradle run configuration with the following configuration parameters

```
Gradle Project: my-test-project
Tasks: bootRun
VM Options: -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=local
Environment variables: spring-boot.run.profiles=local
```

I'm not specifying VM options and env at the same time, just one or the other

Comment: You are on the correct path.
Setting the JVM option `-Dspring.profiles.active=local-1` should work just fine.

Providing some more details would probably help to identify the issue:
1- How are you specifying the `-Dspring.profiles.active`? Are you using an IDE or running a jar file from the command line?
2- What env var are you setting?

Btw, this is a spring-boot thing and not necessarily specific to spring-cloud or spring-cloud-netflix. I'd change the tags to spring-boot if I were you.

Comment: @Sayadi editing the post with my setup information
I think it's specific to spring-cloud-starter because I've other spring boot projects I've setup on intellij with similar config and they work as per the documentation.

Comment: I haven't come across the ’spring-boot.run.profiles’ before. Any reason why you're not using ’spring.profiles.active’?

Comment: Oh sorry that was the last thing I tried, but I have already tried spring.profiles.active

Comment: Aha I see. To further clarify, where exactly are you setting the JVM option; is it in 1- build.gradle or in the 2- Intellij run configurations? If you're relying on setting JVM options in build.gradle and running the application from Intellij, the run configuration in Intellij might be overriding your option from gradle.

Comment: I'm setting it the run options in intellj